# Libre Office Writer - Regular Expression - Rearraging block of paragraphs?

Tags: regex, text, paragraph, libreoffice-writer

I have a text in Libre Office Writer.
These following are paragraphs with different formatting:

**Coronal 132, 25. May 2021.**
Name Middlename Surname
Some paragraph
Link to column

I need it in this order:

Name Middlename Surname: Link to column, Some paragraph, **Coronal 132, 25. May 2021.**

I have whole bunch of these blocks to be rearranged it proper way.

I was trying to do it with Regular Expressions in Libre Office Writer
but LOW froze with this RE:
Edit -> Find & Replace:
(Coronal [0-9]{3}, [0-9]{1,2}. [a-z]{5,9} [0-9]{1,4}.)$*?([a-zA-Z ]+)

I know I wasn't inputting good RE cause I was testing it to work.

Sorry for my English is not so good.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/MEAEy1/1

Comment: I got it to work on regex101 the problem is I don't need new line and it won't work in Libre Office Writer. See regex101.com/r/hX8Uon/1